# Difference between h2o.ai and SparkMLlib from Machine Learning algorithm point of view

Tags: r, machine-learning, sparkr, h2o

Currently, I am doing survey on Machine Learning library using `h2o.ai` and `SparkMLlib`. I have identified that more number of ML algorithms are supported by `h2o.ai` library as compare to `SparkMLlib`, and partition of Spark data frame in to training and testing set seems to be difficult (need to convert spark data frame to R/h2o data frame which is also time/resource consuming).

**What are the others advantages/disadvantages of using `h2o.ai` library over `SparkMLib` or vice-versa ?** I am focusing `h2o.ai` and `SparkMLlib` into R based implementation (SparkR). So the dataframes for h2o `(as.h2o)` and SparkMLlib `(as.DataFrame)` are different.

Comment: opinion based, but useful. one can assume that people are smart enough to recognize opinions and treat them as opinions. I disagree with this SO policy.

Comment: If you're interested, I've created the R shinyML package to quickly compare h2o and Spark machine learning models ( in terms of performance and computation time): https://github.com/JeanBertinR/shinyML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partially, I figure-out the answer using following links: http://datasocial.onsocialengine.com/post/4171645/spark-mllib-or-h2o

Detailed comparative analysis is provided here: https://github.com/szilard/benchm-ml

Slides of bench-marking results: https://speakerdeck.com/szilard/benchmarking-machine-learning-tools-for-scalability-speed-and-accuracy-la-ml-meetup-at-eharmony-june-2015

Video of bench-marking results: https://vimeopro.com/eharmony/talks/video/132838730

Technical report on Analysis of Machine Learning Library: https://github.com/chauhansaurabhb/Analysis-of-H2O-vs-SparkMLlib/blob/master/MLLibrary.pdf